# Why won't iTunes import some VBR files?

Tags: itunes, mp3, media

I've got a few entire albums, and a few tracks from different albums, which iTunes for Windows has refused to import (since the latest major version upgrade, and also before). I have done the following to the files:

- Renamed the MP3 files themselves
- Moved the MP3s to different folders
- Updated/editted the ID3 tags
- Changed ID3 tages between v2.3 and v2.4 and v1.1
- Totally removed the iTunes library XML files and associated folders
- Completely uninstalled and reinstalled iTunes
- Tried this on both Windows and OSX boxes

I hope I'm not crazy, but I simply can't get these files to import. In addition, I can't even play the MP3s in iTunes; it simply doesn't do anything when I use the Explorer context menu to say "Play this in iTunes..." despite the fact that the files play on every other media player known to man.

Am I missing something? Does iTunes do some sort of secret check that the files are failing?

Comment: Do you know how the albums and tracks were ripped in the first place? Is there something in common there?

Comment: I ripped myself with EAC+LAME and used -v0 encoding. Strange thing is on some albums, half the tracks work. So I'm not sure it's encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes cannot play certain VBR encoded MP3 files. Convert them to AAC and they'll run fine. Why  ? I don't know. Faced the same problem as you.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that a transcode to MP3 would work as well. At this point I'm very curious about what exactly makes the files unable to be imported. I'd like to avoid this hassle in the future.

Comment: @Zac Yes, a transcode should work as well. TBH I don't know what was so special about them - and I didn't bother looking up - I'll try to find something on this.